# How to stop NSScrollView's animation when removing a cell

Tags: animation, nsscrollview

I'm currently making an OS X app with an NSScrollView. The scroll view's cells have a small "X" in them that allows me to remove them one at a time. However, whenever a cell is removed, the lower cells get pushed up to fill the space via a short animation. I'm wondering how to disable this animation so that the lower cells are instantly pushed up as soon as the cell is removed. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: The contents of the scroll view are maintained via an NSArrayController, so removing clicking the "x" sends a notification to an observing delegate which in turn calls:

```
-(void)alertRemoved:(NSNotification*)notification{

    // Random code
    ...
    [eventArrayController removeObject:alert];
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? makes it easier to figure out what you are doing

Comment: @Chrene Edited to include some code, hope it helps!

Comment: More interested in the code that removes the cell. I guess you can just disable animations globally, and then restore them afterwards for a quick hack